# Migrating dynamic ASP website to Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I am looking for an advice. I have an ASP website, where pages are generated from database. I have URL, title, content, metatags and other page specific fields in DB tables.

I would like to reuse this databse in Umbraco and be able to generate dynamic pages from these data. I will want to use Razor in views. My dynamic pages will need to be integrated with CMS sitemap. 
I will also need a backend to manage these data (added in Umbraco backend if possible).

Is that possible? What would be the high level steps?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

The data have multiple relationships and business logic needs to be applied before presenting them to the users. What I am looking for is a CMS that will allow me to define routes and inject search, index and detail partials (use global layout, set page title and metatags). It can be a more or less hacky solution as long as CMS updates don't break it.

Is Umbraco flexible enough to do such thing?

Answer (score 3):

Many people who look at Umbraco for the first time try to work out how they can fit an existing project into umbraco and reuse code / databases.

The truth is that using Umbraco involves a shift in how you think about data.  Essentially, in most cases, Umbraco *is* your database. Especially if *all* your database is doing is providing the data that you describe ie the contents of the standard pages of your website.

Your approach should be to rebuild the data structure of your site using Umbraco document types.  Umbraco document types provide the data to your page templates (MVC Views).

You should really download Umbraco and take out a subscription to Umbraco TV to shortcut a rather steep, but very worthwhile learning curve.

Wing

Comment: I should add that while you are installing Umbraco you have the choice to add one of the starter sites. This is a really great way to see how common websites can be structured in Umbraco.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that it would be the correct way of implementing that. Unfortunatelly this problem is more complicated. The data have multiple relationships and business logic needs to be applied before presenting them to the users. What I am looking for is a CMS that will allow me to define routes and inject search, index and detail partials (use global layout) for these data (plug in my application into a CMS). It can be a more or less hacky solution. Is Umbraco flexible enough to do such thing?

Comment: Your question is too vague - I don't know enough about your project.  I would suggest that the only person who would be able to answer the question is you - you need to learn more about Umbraco.